# JAX-RS JsonIngore multiple endpoints

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

How can I achieve to suppress certain fields based on endpoints? @JsonIngore a field suppresses totally.

For instance:

```
Class A () {

    int id;
    String name;
    List list;

}

@Path("endpoint1")
public class Resource1 {

    private A a;
    ...

}

@Path("endpoint2")
public class Resource2 {

    private A a;
    ...

}
```

Now, in endpoint1, I want to show list of B, but not in endpoint2.

Since I couldn't answer my question due to the reputation, I just post the solution here, using @JsonView.

```
    public interface View {
        public interface Public {};
        public interface Endpoint1 extends Public {};
    }

    Class A () {
        int id;
        String name;
        @JsonView(View.Endpoint1.class)
        List list;
    }

    @Path("endpoint1")
    public class Resource1 {
        private A a;
        ...
        @GET
        @JsonView(View.Endpoint1.class)
        @Produces({"application/json"})
        public A generate() {
            ...
        }
    }

    @Path("endpoint2")
    public class Resource2 {
        private A a;
        ...
    }
```

For more information, check http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews